# How to split text contain multiple symbol into an array in react native?

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I'm new in react native and not yet familiar with regex, i want to split text using regex.

I just can handle one symbol of text in react native using below code:

```
mapStringToJSX=(text)=>{
    let rendering=[]
    const nyoba = text.split(/@(.*?)@/g)
    nyoba.map((val,index)=>{
      //handle split text
    })
    return(
      <Text>
        {rendering}
      </Text>
    )
  }
```

Here i can split any text contain `@` on first and last text, but the symbol is gone

For example:

```
string = "sample text contain @at first and last text@"

output = ["sample text contain ", "at first and last text", ""]
```

My question is how can i handle if a `string` contain more than one symbol and keep the symbol exist in array?

> Expected Result:

```
string = "I @have@ a text #contain# two sy@mbol@ or @#even more#@"

output = ["I ", "@have@", " a text ", "#contain#", " two sy", "@mbol@", " or ", "@#even more#@", ""]
```

Comment: So you want to split on both `@` and `#`?

Comment: @CinCout i want to split one or both of them. text `"test @a text@"` or `"test #a text#"` or `"#test# @a text@"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using Regex, you can use character classes and back-references:

- If you want to always match the innermost values, without accepting unpaired nested markers

  ```
  ([#@])([^#@]*?)\1
  ```
- If you want to match the outermost match regardless, use:

  ```
  ([#@])(.*?)\1
  ```

Explaining the first (the others are just variations of the middle part):

1. `([#@])`: A group matching either a # or a @.
2. `([^#@]*?)`: Zero or more characters that are not a # or a @

   - `[^#@]`: The box bracket means "any of", and if the first character is `^` then it means "none of"
   - The group and repetition work exactly as in your original
3. `\1`: Matches exactly the content of the first capture group (so either a # or a @, but most importantly, if the opening was a @ then it will only match the @, so in cases like `foo#bar@lalal` it will not not match `bar` because the start and end markers are different)

---

Also, if you want to test your regular expressions in a more visual way, I highly recommend using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yQIMyp/1), it shows you the matches and the full explanation of the regex you write automatically.

Comment: but on the last symbol, it's not match `@#text#@`, there's a way to make it match? so if the text is `@#text@` it will get **#text** or if a text is `@#text#` it will get `["@", "#text#]`

Comment: Yes, just change the second part back to `(.*?)`. It was unclear if you wanted the inner or outer values. I'll update the answer in a second.